# I don't have permission on my own machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I'm running Ubuntu desktop and I don't have permission to modify some local files on my computer.  IE - within /var/www/ I can't create a new folder unless I sudo.  How do I fix it so by default I have permission without logging in as the root user?

Comment: The answers below are all technically correct, but don't address best practices.  The real answer is that you shouldn't be modifying files in /var/www, you should instead be creating a new site within Apache and pointing the site root to some files which you can access - possibly within your home directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a group (`groupadd group`), and then add yourself and the apache user to that group (`usermod -a -G yourname group`), then chown those files and directories to the group (`chown user:group files`). Make sure the permissions allow group to rwx (e.g. `chmod 775`, instead of `chmod 755`)

Now they're your files, and yet it won't break your web services.

Comment: ...with the addition that if you add yourself to the "www-data" group, you should already have permission to write to that directory.

Comment: @Aquarion: Yep yep.

Comment: The chown isn't working for me.  I've verified that I'm within the "developer" group, but when I run the command the way you wrote it it won't work.

I want to make myself owner of /var/www/ and all of the files that are put there in the future.

Comment: you only need one colon in the command, and again - you shouldn't need to chown, just add yourself to the www-data group.

Comment: How should I configure a live server so we can still make remote modifications but in a secure way?

Answer (score 2):

That behavior is by design in Unix-like systems. It helps prevent grave errors. Sudo is your friend.